Flagging larger than expected changes in number set
I have 378 samples, and every hour on the hour, I get a reading for each. Over the past 48 hours, some readings spiked and I'm trying to flag the samples without having to read each individual reading in excel.
The formula I came up with appears to work but I'm not sure the reason why nor do I have enough math exposure to know if there is a better function to flag the data I'm working with.
(Max Value - (Standard Deviation + Median))/Average
I'm adding an example of what I'm trying to flag. Note, the number set is too long to include all of them here.
DATA SAMPLE ONLY

it's not clear (to me) what the goal is, and my guess is that clarifying the goal would indicate the metric.  If all you want to do is to spot some "surprising" value, you could just keep track of the running mean, and running $\sigma$ and flag if an observation is at least $k\sigma$ off the mean ($k$ being of your choice).  But perhaps you want something else?

Frankly, the outliers in your sample are so far out of line that any metric you choose is going to flag them.

You might be interested in reading about Control Charts.

@lulu spikes in measurement indicate the need for further research of that pool. Because the tests are performed hourly, there shouldn't be much change from hour to hour. So currently, this analysis is being performed manually. It's easy when there are many 0s in the data and then a spike occurs. But in data sets where the numbers are scattered, trying to do so manually takes too much time.

There are a variety of methods for outlier, or anomaly, detection. One of the most common ways is to use some variant of Grubb's test. In a simplified version, for each observation $Y_i$ you calculate the statistic
$$G_i = \frac{|Y_i - \bar{Y}|}{s_Y}$$
where $\bar{Y}$ is the mean of the $Y_i$ values and $s_Y$ is the standard deviation.
Then if $G_i$ is greater than some threshold value $L$, flag observation $i$ as an outlier. You can find a value for $L$ analytically like in the Wikipedia article, or you can just find one that works for your data - a higher value will flag fewer outliers.

Thanks for your response. I have performed this test and while I didn't get the results expected, using your key words "outlier, anomaly detection", I'm going to continue googling methods to have spikes in my data flagged. In addition, Grubbs test did present the use of ABS in the function, which I think would be useful in the function I'm using currently.
